# How to use 2 Submit Buttons with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I need 2 Submit Buttons on my Zend Form. One will save the Form Data, the second will be an Edit Function to return to the first Page of the Form. This is how I create the Submit Form buttons.

```
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'editaction',
                            'type'  => 'submit',
                            'options' => array(
                                        'label'=> 'editaction'),
            'attributes' => array(
                    'value' => 'Edit',
                    'id' => 'editbutton',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg',
                                            'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
            ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submitaction',
                            'type'  => 'submit',
                            'options' => array(
                                        'label'=> 'submitaction'),
            'attributes' => array(
                                    'value' => 'Post your advert',
                                    'id' => 'submitbutton',
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg',
            ),
    ));
```

When I click on the button and check what was send in Firebug, I get the values from both submit buttons. I have tried all sort of different ways in my Controller to find out which submit button was clicked, but it does not seem to work. Below is my last simple test. All I am getting is "Edit". What do I do wrong here?

```
     // Form was send
$request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $postData = $request->getPost();
        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
        if ($request->getPost('editaction') == 'Edit')
        {
            echo 'Edit';
        }
        elseif($request->getPost('submitaction')=='Post your advert'){
             echo 'Submit';
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

After more and more tries I have actually found out that the problem is not Zend Framework 2 instead it is caused by an open source Javascript library. How frustrating, after I thought that I got the Javascript working, I have now got the problem with the rest of the form ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in one of my projects on GitHub, except I use it for save vs. apply (where save saves the form and returns to indexAction, but apply stays on the edit page after saving.)

Two Files:

1. [The View](https://github.com/ardkevin84/zf2-ims/blob/master/module/Application/view/application/inventory-item/edit.phtml)

This is the html for my buttons:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Save">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="applybutton" class="form-control btn btn-warning" value="Apply">
</div>
```

2. [The Controller](https://github.com/ardkevin84/zf2-ims/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/InventoryItemController.php)

There is a `saveAction()` and `applyAction()` that handle the 
buttons in different way. (both call editAction, but they redirect differently)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your solution/project. It's great to see how other people achieve their target. As I wrote in my update on top, the problem was the Javascript Library, which always added all the Submit Buttons. I have now changed the Library to ignore Submit Buttons and since than it works. But still Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could give the two submit buttons the same name instead of different names. Then the post value will be equal to the value of the clicked button.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but if they both have the same name, how do I call the 2 submit buttons in my view with Zend Framework 2. I normally use <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('editaction')); ?>and <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('submitaction')); ?>

Comment: Not a silly question at all. I didn't know that you need to access the elements by name. Maybe there is a way to access them by their (unique) ID?

Comment: To be honest, no idea. To my limited knowledge, it should work the other way as well, but it doesn't, probably because there is a small mistake somewhere....